# AWS (Elastic Beanstalk, RDS). The RDS database becomes unavailable

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I deployed webAPP (Java) using Elastic Beanstalk, RDS(MySQL). HEALTH Status OK!
Access to the database is lost after 1 or 2 days. In the IDEA, when I connect to the database, I get an error [42000][1049] Unknown database 'ebdb'.

I have to rebuild environment (Elastic Beanstalk). But in a time I get that problem again. What is the reason of the error? How I can see in AWS is there database or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen this issue. I have a custom Java Spring BOOT app running on Elastic Beanstlak and queries data from a RDS MySQL instance. Its been running well over a year without issue.

[image]

The database runs fine without any connection issues you are describing. When you look at the RDS instance in the AWS Management Console, what is the status of the database. Is it available - as shown here?

[image]

The URL to the RDS Management console in us-west-2:

https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home

Comment: Now everything is all right. When the problem reappears, I'll take a look. What a scenario are you using
to deploy application? Do you specify the database configuration when creating the application, or do you create the database first, and after creating the application, connect the database to the application?

Comment: I setup the database and make sure I can connect to it from Java Connection class. Basically follow - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html

Comment: I choosed the option "Couple database" for database in my Environment. Can some others problems with app, for example crush of app, make a database unreacheble?

Comment: When I closed public access in RDS Security group, the problem was disappeared. Perhaps, there were many others attempts connections this port and access to DB was becoming unreachable.